I'd like a powershell script to compare a filename with a foldername with some regex
The below script is kind of what I want

Compare a set of input file names in the current folder to subfoldernames within a target folder name supplied on the command line (-targetdir)
Anything within square brackets and any preceding space not included
in the comparison
Any matches moved to a folder for checking

e.g.

Fish.txt should match Fish
Fish.txt should match Fish [xxx]
Fish (1).txt should match Fish (1)
Fish (1) [2].txt should match Fish (1)
Fish (2).txt should not match Fish (1)

I've got to the below but I am stumped.  The regex looks fine but I dont think the regex is being correctly applied to the input filenames or the target folder names.  Any assistance gratefully received
param (
    [string]$targetDir
)

# Define the source and check directories
$sourceDir = Get-Location
$checkDir = Join-Path -Path $sourceDir -ChildPath "check"

# Function to remove text within square brackets
function Remove-Brackets {
    param (
        [string]$input
    )
       return $input -ireplace "\s?\[.*?\]", ""
}

# Get the list of files in the source directory
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -File

# Get the list of folders in the target directory
$targetFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $targetDir -Directory

# Compare and move files
foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {
    $fileName = Remove-Brackets -input $file.Name
    foreach ($folder in $targetFolders) {
        $folderName = Remove-Brackets -input $folder.Name
        if ($fileName -eq $folderName) {
            Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $checkDir
            break
        }
    }
}


Questions are not where you should post answers, they should be below in answers, with some explantation of what you changed.
